# $a$ and $b$ be positive real numbers such that $a + b = 1$. Prove that $a^a \cdot b^b+a^b\cdot b^a≤1$

Tags: number-theory, inequality

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive real numbers such that $a + b = 1$. Prove that
>   $$a^a\cdot b^b+a^b \cdot b^a≤1$$

Comment: For $a=b=0.5$ it doesn't appear to be true. Typo somewhere?

Comment: Instead of $a^b+b^a$, it should be $a^b\cdot b^a$.

Comment: @Roby5. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: Since $a + b = 1$, we can use the Weighted Arithmetic Mean - Geometric Mean inequality to get $$\sqrt[a+b]{a^a b^b} \leq a^2 + b^2.$$ Similarly, write the inequality for the other term to get the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

By the Jensen's inequality,
$$
\log[a^ab^b]=a\log a+b\log b\leq\log[a^2+b^2]\implies a^ab^b\leq a^2+b^2.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\log[a^bb^a]=a\log b+b\log a\leq \log[ab+ba]\implies a^bb^a\leq 2ab.
$$
Summing then gives:
$$
a^ab^b+a^bb^a\leq a^2+b^2+2ab=(a+b)^2=1.
$$